# run a `TRIGGER` in postgres on `ALTER EVENT`

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to run a trigger when an ALTER event happens on my base table. I know we can do trigger on `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE` but not sure if triggers in postgres support `ALTER`.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are looking for [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html).

To create an event trigger that would do something for a specific table, you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (a int);

CREATE FUNCTION trg_alter_test()
     RETURNS event_trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
     obj record;
BEGIN
     FOR obj in SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
         LOOP
              -- Use the name of your table instead of public.test here
              IF obj.objid = 'public.test'::regclass THEN
                   RAISE NOTICE '% altered table: %', tg_tag, obj.objid::regclass::text;
                    END IF;
         END LOOP;
END
$$
;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER test_trigger ON ddl_command_end WHEN TAG IN ('ALTER TABLE')
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_alter_test();
```

If I try to alter public.test, I get this output:

```
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE altered table: test
ALTER TABLE
```

You could obviously change this to whatever you want.

Comment: got it, thanks, I want the event trigger to go only when a alter table is executed on a specific table, can you help me how to do that please ?

Comment: @abhi I added an example.

Comment: thanks, but my database will have lot fo ddl events through out the day.... pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() will have all of those events? if yes, it might take time to loop through them

Comment: It would have to loop through any ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: to be more specific, my alter statement would be 
`ALTER TABLE public.emp1
  INHERIT public.emp`....and the `emp1` table name(basically a child table) keeps changing, I want the trigger to go when such alter statement is executed on `public.emp` table(parent/base table)..can I have a regex like `obj.objid = 'public.emp*'::regclass` ? @Jeremy

Comment: Why use the old style inheritance based partitioning?  If you use declarative partitioning, all of the alter statements would be on the parent.